# Safe thread termination

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, visual-c++, thread-safety

Worker thread handles database updates. When application ends I want to terminate it but without letting it to leave db inconsistent. So I use flags before each significant db operation. After a while, code is full of if's :

```
      void MyWorkerThread::RunMethod(){
      if (false == m_Manager->GetShutdownFlag()) {
         DoSomethingOnDB();
      }
      if (false == m_Manager->GetShutdownFlag()) {
         DoSomethingMoreOnDB();
      }
      ...
```

So, is there any other way to handle shutdown without spamming so many if's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a pattern in your code, which means that you can abstract it as a function:

```
void MyWorkerThread::execDBCommand(auto cmd){
    if  (! m_Manager->GetShutdownFlag()) {
        cmd();
    } else throw std::runtime_error("shutdown"); // or a custom exception
}
```

with an outer `try...catch` for that exception in your `RunMethod` to more directly interrupt processing.

However, the shutdown flag could perhaps be better handled as a signal for the thread, which would then rollback any pending transaction and abort processing, without having to check the state before each instruction. You would also have to mask signals during DB calls.

It depends on your programme architecture of course.

Answer (score 2):

You would be better off synchronizing the threads via some synchronization object (event,lock, mutex, semaphore, critical section, whatever...) or such, so that main thread could wait for worker thread.

Here you have a race condition: what if shutdown flag gets raised immediately after `if` condition is evaluated and before DB operation is executed?

Here's an illustration with mutexes as a well known synchronization primitive, but there are better ways.

Main thread:

```
int main() {
    ... wait for signal to exit the app
    // the DB operations are running on another thread
    ...
    // assume that we start shutdown here
    // also assume that there is some global mutex g_mutex
    // following line blocks if mutex is locked in worker thread:
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(g_mutex); 
    Cleanup(); //  should also ensure that worker is stopped
}
```

The worker thread:

```
void MyWorkerThread::RunMethod() 
{
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(g_mutex); 
    DoSomethingOnDB();
  }
  // some other, non locked execution which doesn't prevent
  // main thread from exiting
  ...
  {
     std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(g_mutex);
     DoSomethingMoreOnDB();
  }
}
```

as obviously you don't want to repeat all the locking, you should wrap it:

```
  void MyWorkerThread::RunMethod() 
  {
    Execute(DoSomethingOnDB);
    ...
    Execute(DoSomethingMoreOnDB);
  }

  void MyWorkerThread::Execute(DatabaseFn fn) 
  {
     std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(g_mutex); 
     fn();
  }
```

Comment: but using lock wouldn't be the same ?  could GetShutdownFlag be perceived as one ?

Comment: no, because lock can prevent the main thread from even going into shutdown if there is a DB operation being executed. Unlike `if`s, lock acquistion blocks if the lock is already taken (lock here meaning a sync primitive in general). Then only after the lock is released in another thread, the first thread will continue.

Comment: Thank You, its really good solution for handling the db thread but doesn't answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have ReaderWriter Locks already in your applications? You should treat Database closing as a Write Operation and get a Writer Lock before starting it. Then none of the other Read(which get a Reader Lock) or Write operations(which get a Writer Lock) can start once the closing is in progress.

Comment: Unfortunately it's fat legacy code and as I am aware of it doesn't contain any of these. And implementing those in my method would be very similar to current situation.

Answer (score 0):

If your Do functions returned something you could then && or || them together so as soon as one of them returns "false" or "true" whichever is the terminating condition, you would stop processing.

What happens if the shutdown flag gets set by a different thread during your operation (or just before executing it?) and what would happen if you ran this process anyway.

Comment: Sorry, but this would make code even less readable. Especially when I would like to add some comments, debug lines etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your flag usage will be limited to the variety of methods which use database: DoSomethingOnDB, DoSomethingMoreOnDB ...

Assuming you use mutexes and locks properly (which does not seem here), you can gather database related methods into a compound method and lock your database there and do a single check bool operation in that single method so that only a single thread make a database operation at a time.

Comment: I don't want to do all changes at once that's why i have different methods

Comment: but all database  methods take action according to m_Manager->GetShutdownFlag(), why not gather them into a single place?

Comment: Imagine total 1 zillion writes in 5 different methods. During execution termination msg comes. One method already finished(it had 1 write operation :P ) and its is perfectly correct for db consistency. But I wouldn't like to wait to end of next 1 zillion -1 writes cos i want to end this process immediately.